# How to let Stepper motor spin constantly?

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper, stepper-motor

When i run the code on the Arduino the Stepper only does a small turn every cycle. How can i make that constantly turning?

```
 #include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position
//Servo Teil
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
// for your motor

// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);

void setup() {
  // set the speed at 60 rpm:
  myStepper.setSpeed(105);
  // initialize the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Servo
    myservo.attach(3);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
    //Servo

}

void loop() {
  // step one revolution  in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
  //Servo
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  //Servo
 

 
}
```

Comment: Does the stepper motor work correctly, when you try it with one of the libraries examples? With your current code the stepper motor should do one revolution (200 steps) per `loop()` iteration (stopping after the 200 steps, then the servos moves and then the stepper starts again in the next iteration).

Comment: rewrite the loop() code ... get rid of the `for` statements ... refer to the example sketch `blinkWithoutDelay` for a way to run code at an interval .... every 15 ms move the stepper, then move the servo ... increment/decrement `pos` accordingly

Comment: Yes it does as you say chrisl. Thx jsotola will try it.

Comment: You don't "let" a stepper rotate, to get it to move you have to *actively* step it. When you're not stepping it it stops.

Comment: create N square waves, where N is the number of phases in your stepper motor. Make sure the N square waves are appropriately out of phase with one another. Connect amplified versions of the square waves to the stepper motor. The motor will rotate continuously, at a speed determined by the frequency of the square waves.